# Cannot open json settings file in my vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Version VScode: 1.51.0
In this version, I want to find the settings.json file of vs-code
[image]

[image]

I can't see how to open Settings as JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *Command Pallet* from the *View* menu

[image]

and then select one from the below options that say *(JSON)* as per your need.

[image]